# must_not is not giving expected result in Elasticsearch for empty field

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

This is my sample es index document:

```
"hits" : [
   {
    "_index" : "project_note",
    "_type" : "project_note",
    "_id" : "19",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "createTime" : "2021-10-04T13:43:55.330",
      "createTimeInMs" : 1633333435330,
      "createdBy" : "test",
      "editTime" : "2021-10-04T13:43:55.330",
      "editTimeInMs" : 1633333435330,
      "editedBy" : "test",
      "versionId" : 1,
      "id" : "19",
      "organizationId" : "28",
      "accessLevel" : "PUBLIC",
      "status" : "ACTIVE",
      "projectId" : "95",
      "userId" : 129,
      "noteType" : "SYSTEM_GENERATED",
      "projectDemographicLogId" : "1"
    },
   {
    "_index" : "project_note",
    "_type" : "project_note",
    "_id" : "19",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "createTime" : "2021-10-04T13:43:55.330",
      "createTimeInMs" : 1633333435330,
      "createdBy" : "test",
      "editTime" : "2021-10-04T13:43:55.330",
      "editTimeInMs" : 1633333435330,
      "editedBy" : "test",
      "versionId" : 1,
      "id" : "19",
      "organizationId" : "28",
      "accessLevel" : "PUBLIC",
      "status" : "ACTIVE",
      "projectId" : "95",
      "userId" : 129
     
    }
]
```

In the first doc, it has `noteType` but in the second, I don't have that field stored in db.
I want to exclude  the documents where noteType==null or noteType is absent.
But, I am getting only the docs which have `noteType="SYSTEM_GENERATED"`

My approach:

```
{
  "query":
  {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "projectId" : {
            "value" : "95",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "createTimeInMs" : {
            "from" : null,
            "to" : 1633594455000,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "noteType" : {
            "value" : "SYSTEM_GENERATED",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
  
}
```

Equivalent java code:

```
  BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder= QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
               queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("projectId", requestInfo.getProjectId()));
               queryBuilder.must(rangeQuery("createTimeInMs").lte(requestInfo.getCreateTimeInMs()));

               if(!requestInfo.isIncludeLog()) {
                 
                   queryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery("noteType", Defs.SYSTEM_NOTE_TYPE));
                 
               }
```

Comment: based on the above sample index data, what is your expected search result ?

Comment: I have correct a line in the java code portion.  I want to exclude documents which have `noteType='system-generated'` values

Comment: that means your expected search result is the second document ?

Comment: yes, I want to fetch only the second doc

Comment: Note that none of the two documents have `projectId: 96` and none have the `projectId` field at all

Comment: @Val, corrected, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

If only the `must_not` part of the query is used (excluding the `must` part)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "noteType.keyword": {
              "value": "SYSTEM_GENERATED",
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

The search result is similar to what you expect to get

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "69477995",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "createTime": "2021-09-26T15:54:08.373",
          "createTimeInMs": 1632650048373,
          "createdBy": "test",
          "editTime": "2021-09-26T15:54:08.373",
          "editTimeInMs": 1632650048373,
          "editedBy": "test",
          "versionId": 1,
          "id": "18",
          "note": "note-1, simple note ",
          "organizationId": "28",
          "accessLevel": "PUBLIC",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "taskId": "5",
          "userId": 129
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @user404 can you please share your index mapping of `noteType` field ?

Comment: I unintentioally copied the a slightly wrong data but the structure and idea are same[updated the docs].  Here, I need to search them by projected and createTimeInMs as I have added in my java code.

Comment: `noteType` is just a plan String, no keyword is used

Comment: yes @user404 but the term query works for the `keyword` type field. In your mapping, you might have defined `noteType` field to be of `text` type. Have you explicitly declared the index mapping, or you are using the default one ?

Comment: I am using the default one. No key is specified for noteType. Just simply defined: `private String noteType;`

Comment: any workaround to solve this? without defining that as termquery?